# Android studio doesnt work after updating windows

Tags: android-studio

I installed android studio on my windows 7 OS about 1 month ago and it was working most of times.
But last week, I changed my OS to windows 10, after that android studio doesn't work and shows the following message error:

[image]

I have tried compiling using the terminal, but it didn't solve the problem.
Do you know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are good.

I just want to state that there is most important plugin called gradle which is missing from your android development environment as the picture shown the error. There is some link down below in your android studio console to download or upgrade the android studio after the download or update the android studio. you will be able to work in android environment.

Thanks.